# Congruence system.

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I have this problem, I need to find the smallest possible solution

x≡3(mod10),x≡11(mod13),x≡15(mod17).
x≡3(mod10),x≡11(mod13),x≡15(mod17).
I used Chinese remainder theorem and found that: x1=3,x2=11 , and x3=−45??

The solutions would be congruent to v=(13×17)×3+(10×17)×11+(10×13)×(−45)=−3317(mod10×13×17)v=(13×17)×3+(10×17)×11+(10×13)×(−45)=−3317(mod10×13×17). Is that the smaller solution? Is x3=−45x3=−45 correct?

My question is how I can reduce -3317 to have a positive answers.

Comment: Add twice $(10)(13)(17)$.

Comment: x3 is the solution of ( 10*13) x3 congruent 15 mod 17, using Euclidian Algorithm I fund this linear combination 1= 17 (23) + (-3) (10*13) but I have to multiply by 15 because in the original system the 3rd equation is congruence 15 mod 17. then 15= 17 ( 23* 15) + (10*13) ( -3* 45).

Comment: I am not sure where you suggest to add twice (10)(13)(17)

Comment: To $-3317$. The result will then be congruent to $-3317$ modulo $(10)(13)(17)$ and the result will be between $0$ and $(10(13)(17)$.

Comment: oh!!!!! got it! Thanks Andre.

Comment: You are welcome.